# Options to get a point in the form of (n,k)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to write a recursive function that prints out the ways to reach a point where N and K are positive so for example if the point is (1,1)
r= right
u = up

So  the function will print ur ,ru.
If the point is (2,2) then the possible steps are: rruu, ruru, urru, uurr
I have bulited a function that print **all** the combination that  posibale of the r and u posibale(when it contains also rrrr or uuuu). but i need only the sequences that num of 'r' = num of 'u'.
The func i have written suposse to help the function i wanted

```
def assist_print_sequences(char_list, last_seq, n):
    # base case
    if n > 0:
        for char in char_list:
            # looping over all the chars in list and adds them to last chars until n<1.
            assist_print_sequences(char_list, last_seq + char, n-1)
    # when n is smaller than 1.
    else:
        print(last_seq)
```

Comment: Please add your code to the question

Comment: Your question is also unclear... what are the unwanted ones? Don't you want all the ways to reach the point?

Answer (score 2):

Seems that what you want is a permutation of `target`

```
target = ["r"] * n + ["u"] * k
target_string = "".join(target)
```

Then pick an answer from [How to generate all permutations of a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list-in-python) and you have all paths to the point you aim for, recursively (permutations can be found recursively)